# Vue CLI 3: hot reloading takes a long time to rebuild

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli-3

I've updated a big project in order to to use Vue CLI 3, but ever since I've done it hot reloading is painfully slow:

- As soon as I open a .vue file, it auto-rebuilds out of nowhere taking 10-15 seconds to do so
- Every time I save, I have to wait 10-15 seconds again

That never happened before CLI 3. Is there any sort of caching mechanism I need to activate?

Comment: Similar to this perhaps? https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1159

Comment: Without any code to look at, this question really does belong on [Github](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues) or [Discord](https://vue-land.js.org/). There's nothing anybody here is going to be able answer

Answer (score 0):

Posting for anyone stumbling into the same issue. Turns out this was related to the way I was using the `style-resources-loader` plugin (that allows me to have SASS variables globally available).

I thought we needed to load all styles in order for the plugin to map things, but in reality we only need to bind the global styles we want:

```
  pluginOptions: {
    'style-resources-loader': {
      preProcessor: 'scss',
      patterns: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, './src/shared/assets/styles/vars/_all.scss')
      ]
    }
  }
```

These files are rebuilt every time you trigger a component, hence the huge hot reloading time (this project has *a lot* of SCSS).